# Rotate all images in a folder

Tags: matlab, image-processing, rotation

I have some images that I rotate with an angle that I choose.
I want that, after I rotate the first image, all the other images will rotate with the same angle and all images will be saved in the original file locations.

This is the code I use to rotate all images

```
function [ output_args ] = cut( filename)
global angle;
global ir;
frames(filename);
rotationGUI('frames/001.jpg')
for i = 1 : 219 
   ir= imrotate('frames/%0.3i.jpg',angle);

end
end
```

This is the code that rotates the first image

```
function [ angle ] = rotationGUI(a)

I = imread(a);
hFig = figure('menu','none');
hAx = axes('Parent',hFig);

hTxt = uicontrol('Style','text', 'Position',[290 28 20 15], 'String','0');
uicontrol('Parent',hFig, 'Style','slider', 'Value',0, 'Min',0,...
    'Max',360, 'SliderStep',[1 10]./360, ...
    'Position',[150 5 300 20], 'Callback',{@slider_callback,I,hAx,hTxt,hFig})


uicontrol(hFig,'Style','pushbutton','String','Save and Close',...
    'Position',[10 20 120 40],'Callback',{@ok_Callback,I,hTxt,hFig,a});

  %# show image
imshow(I, 'Parent',hAx)
%# Callback function
return;
end
    function slider_callback(hObj, eventdata,I,hAx,hTxt,hFig)
global angle
global Irot
angle = round(get(hObj,'Value'));        %# get rotation angle in degrees

Irot = imrotate(I,angle);
imshow(Irot, 'Parent',hAx)  %# rotate image
set(hTxt, 'String',num2str(angle))       %# update text
end

function ok_Callback(hObj, eventdata,I,hTxt,hFig,path1)

global Irot
global angle
set(hTxt, 'String','save')
imwrite(Irot,path1);

delete(hFig);
end
```

The problem is the following errors

```
Error in imrotate (line 113)
   B = zeros(new_size,class(A));

Error in cut (line 7)
   ir= imrotate('frames/%0.3i.jpg',angle);
```

Comment: what's `'frames/%0.3i.jpg'`? aren't you missing `sprintf` here? and shouldn't the format string be `'frames%03d.jpg'`? And what exactly is the error you are getting at line 113 of `imrotate`?

Comment: @Shai אהלן שי .. frames/%0.3i.jpg it's the name of foulder with images... the error of imrotate it's not from my code it's from the MATLAB CODE

Comment: (1) this is an English website - please do not use foreign languages. (2) please copy paste the detailed error you get from Matlab, not just where it occurred.

Comment: @Shai a title befoere the error "Trailing string input must be a valid numeric class name." 
  if islogical(A)
                    B = false(new_size);
                else
                    B = zeros(new_size,class(A));
                end
                
                for k = 1:thirdD
                    B(v{1},v{2},k) = rot90(A(v{1},v{2},k),multiple_of_ninety);
                end

Comment: @Shai's comment is correct. You need to use `sprintf`. Also your formating string is wrong because you want to format an integer not a floating type. `frames/%03d.jpg` is the correct format. Finally, even though the error is in the Matlab code, the exact error message is still useful for debugging. Always read and research error messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer

```
function [ output_args ] = FramesRotate()
global ir;
global numFrames
global angle
%frames(filename);
%rotationGUI('frames/001.jpg')
for i = 2 : numFrames 
img=imread( sprintf( 'frames/%03i.jpg', i ) ); 
ir=imrotate( img, angle); 
imwrite(ir,sprintf( 'frames/%03i.jpg', i ) );


end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

[`imrotate(A, angle)`](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/images/ref/imrotate.html) takes two arguments, an image, `A` and an `angle`.

Your error message tells you that line 7 of your `cut` function is throwing an error.

```
ir= imrotate('frames/%0.3i.jpg',angle);
```

This is because 'frames/%0.3i.jpg' is not an image. It is a string.

You need to load your image using a function like [`imread`](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/imread.html) before you can use `imrotate`.

Comment: i change tge to code to
 `file_name = imread('frames/%0.3i.jpg');
   imrotate(file_name,angle);
`
but it write to me **Error using imread (line 350)
File "frames/%0.3i.jpg" does not exist.

Error in cut (line 6)
file_name = imread('frames/%0.3i.jpg');**

Comment: You don't want to add "frames/%0.3i.jpg", you want to add "frames/001.jpg", right? To replace the `%0.3i` with the correct number you need to use [`sprintf`](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/sprintf.html) to format your string, as suggested by Shai. Error messages are your friend.

Comment: see [my comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25304238/rotate-all-images-in-a-folder?noredirect=1#comment39439722_25304238): `img=imread( sprintf( 'frames/%03d.jpg', i ) );` then `imrotate( img, angle);`

Comment: ok ...tnx know my code working some times and sometimes write a mistake 
 
my code is :
` function [ output_args ] = cut( filename)
global angle;
global ir;
rotationGUI('frames/001.jpg')
for i = 2 : 219 
img=imread( sprintf( 'frames/%03i.jpg', i ) ); 
ir=imrotate( img, angle); 
imwrite(ir,sprintf( 'frames/%03i.jpg', i ) );

end
end   `
the error the he write
** Dimensions of matrices being concatenated are not consistent. Error in imrotate (line 134)
        rotate = maketform('affine',[ cos(phi)  sin(phi)  0; ...

Error in cut (line 8)
ir=imrotate( img, angle); **

Comment: The error message should help you. It says that there is a problem at cut (line 8). Add a breakpoint and check the values of your variables. Is everything what you would expect it to be?

Comment: @Shai can i make a program to run line after line ? because as i see the problem with the program that run in threads

Comment: @user2347210 There is a [tutorial on Matlab debugging](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/matlab_prog/debugging-process-and-features.html#brqxeeu-177). You can step into functions and step line by line through your code using the Matlab editor.

Comment: @user2347210 use debug options in matlab: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/debugging-process-and-features.html